# How do i increase the input impedance of an inverting amplifier constructed using an op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I learnt about bootstrapping a non-inverting amplifier to increase its input impedance. Is there any similar way to increase the input impedance of the inverting amplifier?

Comment: Precede it with a bootstrapped non-inverting amplifier?

Comment: @spehro-pefhany Can you explain it a bit further?

Comment: Buffer then invert (two amplifiers). The first amplifier provides high input impedance, the second provides inversion or inverting gain.

Answer (score 1):

Buffer then invert (two amplifiers). The first amplifier (a bootstrapped follower) provides high input impedance, the second provides inversion or inverting gain.

If you feedback from an inverting amplifier to the input you will *lower* the input impedance. In the extreme, this is what a transimpedance amplifier does- the input is a virtual ground, so (ideally) 0\$\Omega\$ input impedance.

You could also try to bootstrap some analog of the input voltage from the output of the inverting amplifier (invert it again, and reverse the gain) but chances are that would not work too well (it would have poor performance or oscillate) because of the multiple stages. This kind of thing is done sometimes to actively drive shields (guards) to the common mode voltage on differential-input amplifiers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about how the inverting amplifier operates in order to understand whether this is possible.

When the feedback loop is closed, the voltage at the inverting input is equal to that at the non-inverting input. That means that you can consider the inverting-input node to be a zero-impedance point.

In addition to the above, the reason that you are able to bootstrap the non-inverting amplifier is that the amplifier output is in phase with the input.

Take the above information and figure out for yourself whether it is possible to use bootstrap techniques to increase the input impedance of an inverting amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the topology of the amplifier. For a BJT inverting amplifier, adding a resistor at the emitter creates negative feedback on Vbe (reducing the gain, as expected with negative feedback) but the impedance seen into the base is multiplied by the beta of the transistor. I.e. you put 1mA into the base, which causes beta * 1mA to flow through the emitter resistor, raising the voltage at the emitter as if you where injecting 1mA into a resistor of R = beta * Re:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYxdkd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**UPDATE**: Sorry, I just noticed in the title that you where referring to Op-Amp amplifiers. At least this might help understanding feedback in general anyway.

Comment: For a MOS version, the input impedance is already infinite (at DC at least), so it makes little sense to use this technique to reduce it.